# TypeError: Cannot read property 'from' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

i am trying to make a firebase push notification application
and while uploading the script i am having this error.i dont understand the cannot read property error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'from' of undefined
   at admin.firestore.collection.doc.collection.doc.get.then.queryResult 
    (/user_code/index.js:16:48)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

and here is my node.js script

```
'use-strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

 exports.sendNotification = 
  functions.firestore.document("Users/{user_id}/Notifications/{notification_id}")
    .onWrite((change,context)=> {

const user_id = context.params.user_id;
const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

console.log("User ID : " + user_id + " | Notification ID : " + notification_id);

return admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(user_id).collection("NotificationsN").doc(notification_id).get().then(queryResult =>{

    const from_user_id = queryResult.data().from;

    const from_data = admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(from_user_id).get();
    const to_data = admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(user_id).get();

    return promise.all([from_data, to_data]).then(result =>{

      const from_name = result[0].data().name;
      const to_name = result[1].data().name;

      console.log("FROM : " + from_name +" TO : " + to_name)
      return null;
    }).catch(error => {
   console.error(error);
  res.error(500);
 });

  }).catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
  res.error(500);
  });
 });
```

Comment: Means `queryResult.data()` returns `undefined`

Comment: how can i solve that problem

Comment: Figure out what is `queryResult` and make sure what you are querying exists

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code that tries to read the document from the subcollection:

```
return admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(user_id).collection("NotificationsN").doc(notification_id).get().then(queryResult =>{
```

Note the `N` in `NotificationsN`? That is not present in the code that triggers the function:

```
functions.firestore.document("Users/{user_id}/Notifications/{notification_id}")
```

To fix the error, simply remove the trailing `N`, leaving:

```
return admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(user_id).collection("Notifications").doc(notification_id).get().then(queryResult =>{
```

But note that the whole operation is unnecessary: you're (re)loading the document that triggered the function to being with. That document is already passed into your function in `change.after`, so you don't have to reload it. You can instead just use it direct from there:

```
from_user_id = change.before.data().from;
```